# OBIEE:how to reload rpd file quickly?

Tags: oracle, obiee

I'm new to use oracle BIEE.My development enviromnent now is installed,and the project is a little big.Multi user development is using for developing now.The problems happens when one developer publish the rpd to network and want to test the  data,the server reloading the rpd file takes too much time and I can hardly wait!When multi users want to test rpd file,e,can't stand it... is there any other way to solve the problem?or how to make the biee sever reload the rpd file quickly?

Comment: PLEASE EDIT YOUR TITLE TO NOT BE ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say specifically without knowing a bit more about your setup, but here are a few general advice pointers:

- When stopping the service OBI will wait for any running queries to complete before stopping the service, so making sure there's nothing running before you try to do this.
- Make sure you're only restarting the BI Server component, you don't need to wait for the other services to restart if you're just changing the RPD (if you're on 11g then deploying through EM should mean this happens anyway so you don't need to worry).
- If you're using 11g, you could try [incremental updates by creating patches](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2010/07/obiee-11gr1-incremental-patches-to-the-rpd/).
- Check whether the hardware you're running on is adequate, most importantly that you've enough RAM so it's not having to page out to disk when it loads the RPD.
- Remove anything unused from the RPD to make it smaller.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I'm now reading the incremental updates by creating patches.We use oracle 11g,and restart it through Em.Our development has changed from windows sever to aix,and it seems to be fast a lillte now when trying to restart the BI  Server component.Our rpd file sizes 700kb now ,em,I can hardly remove anything unused,is it a little big?I'm new and don't konw much about it.Another question is that I can't 【publish to netowrk】 if I write Chinese instead of English commit message,why is it..

Comment: I've read the article,but I can't understand it ,if I open the production rpd,I can only use the read-only mode if the production rpd is used by server,is it so？Now I can't test it because I can't access the aix now - -!Later I'll try it or you can tell me ,thanks -.-

Comment: Em...I have anthoer question is that I can't edit share rpd through ftp share filesystem,I can't work when the development has changed to aix server...